# Using generics for classes with and without an array: Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'string[]'

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface

I have a simple interface:

```
interface Animal<T> {
  isMatch: (value: T) => boolean
}
```

with these implementations:

```
class Dog implements Animal<string> {
  isMatch(input: string): boolean {
    // do something with string
  }
}
```

and

```
class Cat<T extends T[]> implements Animal<T> {
  isMatch(input: T[]): boolean {
    // do something with list
  }
}
```

I can instantiate a `Dog` without issue with:

```
const dog = new Dog("pug")
```

However, I can't instantiate a `Cat` with any of:

```
const siamese = new Cat<string>(...) // Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'string[]'

const persian = new Cat<string[]>(...) // Type 'string[]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string[][]'

const sphynx = new Cat(["birman"]) // Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'string[]'
```

I've used the generics / extends based on examples I've seen online, so not sure what I'm misunderstanding here.

Comment: What is `T extends T[]` supposed to do? As in, what did you expect/want to happen?

Comment: I expected it to let me use `T[]` as the input for the `isMatch` function, without it the compiler complains that `This type parameter might need an 'extends T[]' constraint.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand why you used `T extends T[]`, because of this error when you don't:

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.(2416)
>
> input.tsx(11, 11): This type parameter might need an `extends T[]`
> constraint.

This error is misleading in this case, but if we think through what we want, we can get the solution.

You want `isMatch` to take the type `T[]`. However, `Cat` only takes `T`. Remember that `isMatch` is defined by the interface `Animal`, and in the interface, it takes `T` (in the interface). If we want these types to match, we just have to make `Animal` take `T[]`!

```
class Cat<T> implements Animal<T[]> {
```

And that's it.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBRMpN)

Comment: Oh wow, that's simpler than expected - thank you! Will mark as the accepted answer when it lets me :)